# Не могу настроить проверку ввода python

Tags: python

Ребят, есть задача:

На стандартном потоке ввода задаются два целых числа, не меньшие -32000 и не большие 32000. На стандартный поток вывода напечатайте сумму этих чисел.
Числа задаются по одному в строке. Пробельные символы перед числом и после него отсутствуют. Пустые строки в вводе отсутствуют.

Не могу понять, как проверять числа на заданные критерии.
`if(type(a)!=int)`: - не будет работать, так как на входе всегда string.
`isdigit()` тоже не работает, так как не пропускает знак "-".

Я понимаю, что решение какое-то простое и очевидное, видимо, в силу неопытности - жестко туплю :(

Comment: а зачем проверять - в условиях написано, что всё хорошо будет :) А вообще, `try: i = int(input()); except:`

Comment: Лучше добавьте в вопрос пример своего кода. А так, `a = int(input())` и `b = int(input())`. Это минимум, если будет введено не число, будет ошибка, это можно ловить исключением через try/except как написали ранее

Answer (score 0):

тут должно быть все понятно:

```
>>> x= "-32"
>>> y="32"
>>> print x-y
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print x-y
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(x-y)?
>>> print(x-y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
>>> print(int(x)+int(y))
0
>>> type (x)
<class 'str'>
>>> type (int(x))
<class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res=[]
while True:
   if len(res)>=2:
       break
   i=int(input('num'))
   if -32000<i<32000:
       res.append(i)
    else:
        print('wrong input')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]